# Конвертировать список строк или строковое поле SQL в datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, pandas, datetime

Получаю из `postgresql` поле строк, в виде списка строк, которые выглядят как дата-время:

```
2022-12-29 01:17:59.274000
```

Надо получить список/массив/pd.Series из объектов `datetime.datetime`.

Не было бы проблем, если бы среди этих строк не попадались бы такие:

```
2022-12-29 01:17:59
```

И когда я пытаюсь применить:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

или аналогично для `Pandas`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date_time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

То получаю `ValueError`, о том, что для `.%f` не найдено значение.

Я написал костыль:

```
def convert_str_date(x):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(x+'.0' if '.' not in x else x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
list_date_time = list(map(convert_str_date, list_str)
```

Что-то такое же можно и для `Pandas` написать и применить с `.apply`.

Потом я решил, что, возможно, есть способ сразу получать из `SQL` сконвертированные данные, но я нашел только to_date/to_time, которые отдельно конвертят дату и отдельно время, а как это сделать вместе - не нашел.

Итак, вопросы:

1. Есть ли способ, не писать костыль, который будет добавлять '.0'. Возможно, есть какой-то прием в шаблонах datetime, типа как в регулярных выражениях.
2. Есть ли способ сразу получить из SQL вот такие данные в нужном формате?

Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

1. Да есть. Написать другой костыль с использованием регулярных выражений))
2. Попробуйте в SQL запросе использовать что-то вроде `to_char(your_datetime_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US')`

Answer (score 0):

Есть частичный ответ на первый вопрос, есть решение для Pandas:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date_time, format='mixed')
```

Остается вопрос для базового питона.

Есть ответ и на второй вопрос:

```
SELECT date_time_field::timestamp from table
```

**UPD.** Есть вариант для стандартных библиотек, но он такой медленный, что даже не знаю, стоит ли указывать.

```
from dateutil import parser
date_time_list = list(map(parser.parse, list_str))
```

Работает в 7 раз медленнее, чем мой костыльный способ.

Пока по скорости выигрывает запрос к `postgres` с конвертацией. Вариант с `Pandas` в два раза медленнее. Костыльный вариант в 4 раза медленнее чем  `Pandas`.

Все еще жду хорошего решения для стандартных библиотек.